# Python: How to handle UDP packets larger than the max UDP safe packet size?

Tags: python, sockets, udp, python-asyncio, datagram

I am having problems with receiving UDP packets larger than the maximum safe UDP size. I am using python with asyncio, where I have created a UdpReceiver class, which implements the base class for implementing datagram (UDP) protocols (asyncio.DatagramProtocol). The data is received in the following method:

```
def datagram_received(self, raw_data: bytes, addr: Tuple[str, int]) -> None
```

However, if the data being sent is over the maximum safe UDP payload, it is fragmented into different packages. Does anyone know if it is possible to overcome the maximum safe UDP payload on a network? I do not need to get every single message, so I do not need to receive all the packages being sent. If not, how can I buffer the data to combine all the fragments from a single message?

Max payload size: The maximum safe UDP payload is 508 bytes, whereas the packet size is 576, with a maximum 60-byte IP header and the 8-byte UDP header.

Asyncio: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-protocol.html

Comment: You don't have to reassemble the fragments. The IP layer does that, if and when all the fragments arrive. But a limit is a limit. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @user207421 only in books)

Comment: @eri Only in books, RFCs, and Internet hosts. Your point?

Comment: Do you have host on hosting or on another provider? Try your self. Fragmented udp works in local network, but not in internet.

Comment: How exactly is that inconsistent with what I wrote?

Answer (score -2):

Routers generaly cuts or drops UDP fragments greather than MTU.

Send packet with maximum size and `dont fragment` flag. On server you recieved fragment cutted. Send recieved size to client and use it as maximum payload.

Safe way to use UDP is create protocol over it. Add header with size, sequence numbers... Read about RTP (rfc3550)

I tried send 1500 bytes. On  local network UDP reasembled. On Internet all fragments is not recieved on other side.

Comment: Routers will *fragment* UDP *datagrams* greater than the MTU, and the whole point of fragmentation is to make the fragments *smaller* than the MTU.

Comment: Not all, maybe u believe fragmentation, but reality is not so good

Comment: I do not understand your comment. Not all what? What shouldn't I believe? What reality? Please clarify. And please justify your extraordinary claim that routers cut datagrams. They don't. They can't. They fragment them.

Comment: That's enough waffle. Please provide the make and model of a router that doesn't do fragmentation, and of a router that cuts datagrams, in clear violation of the UDP RFC.